# why is VIEW menu missing the ROTATE button

Tags: solidworks

According to [solidworks 2012 docs](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/r_view_toolbar.htm?id=21a63b42d5c4489f9cd59b5db5fc6781#Pg0), the VIEW menu should have the ROTATE VIEW button (as well as the PAN button).

However, my SolidWorks 2012 VIEW menu does not have it ... see screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidworks present that toolbar with some of its toolbar buttons as default. Since there are a lot more than that they do not just want to put all of them there.

I found something that you can add any button there (including Rotate View). The document is for SolidWorks 2013 but it worked for my Solidworks 2011, therefore I believe it will work for SolidWorks 2012 too:

http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_heads_up_view_toolbar.htm

Comment: here's my new question: why was the rotate button not already present ... it is difficult for me to imagine 3d software without rotation ...

Answer (score 0):

B. Emre's solution shows how to put a button into a toolbar.

But you can also put a button into your "mouse gestures" (rightClick+drag in a view panel opens the mouse gestures thing).

go to TOOLS/CUSTOMIZE/MOUSE GESTURES ... search for "rotate" ... then assign it to one of the "mouse gestures" ... now the rotate button is just a right-click away.